# How do I get the user to click on the random button (1,10) in order to guess which button has diamond hidden? User has got 3 attempts

Tags: python, tkinter

A user has got 10 buttons and the diamond is hidden in one by using random function.
User has got three attempts to find out in which box is the diamond.

```
      from tkinter import * 
      import tkinter.messagebox as msgBox
      window = Tk()
      window.title("Find the diamond")
      window.configure(bg="gray", pady=100)
      window.geometry("720x420")
      window.resizable(0,0)
      number_of_guesses = 0
      random_box_number = (1,10)

      HideTheDiamond = Button(window, text = "Hide the diamond", bg ="green")


      import random
      import sys

      Button1 = Button(window, text = "1", width=10,height=3, bg="yellow")
      Button2 = Button(window, text = "2",width=10,height=3, bg="blue")
      Button3 = Button(window, text = "3",width=10,height=3, bg="dark red")
       
      Button4 = Button(window, text = "4",width=10,height=3, bg="green")
      Button5 = Button(window, text = "5", width=10,height=3, bg="red")
      Button6 = Button(window, text = "6",width=10,height=3, bg="purple")
      Button7 = Button(window, text = "7",width=10,height=3, bg="brown")
      Button8 = Button(window, text = "8",width=10,height=3, bg="orange")
      Button9 = Button(window, text = "9",width=10,height=3, bg="dark blue")
      Button10 = Button(window, text = "10", width=10,height=3, bg="pink")
      label11=Label(window,text="Click the Hid the diamond button to start the game. \n Then, 
      click on the box where you think the diamond is.\n You have three guesses to find 
      it.",bg="gray")






      Button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10,sticky=W)
      Button2.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button3.grid(row=1, column=3,padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button4.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button5.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button6.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button7.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button8.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button9.grid(row=2, column=4,padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      Button10.grid(row=2, column=5,padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
      label11.grid(row =5, column =2, sticky=W)
      HideTheDiamond.grid(row=5, column =5)


       HideTheDiamond.configure(state=NORMAL)
       label11.configure(width=40, height=10)
       Button1.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button2.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button3.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button4.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button5.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button6.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button7.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button8.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button9.configure(state=DISABLED)
       Button10.configure(state=DISABLED)
       
       import random
      @staticmethod
      def random(self):
         global_number_of_guesses = 0
         global_box_number = random.randint(1, 10)

         return global_box_number


       HideTheDiamond.configure(command=random)

        
        def connect():
         Button1.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button2.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button3.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button4.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button5.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button6.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button7.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button8.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button9.configure(state=NORMAL)
         Button10.configure(state=NORMAL)
         HideTheDiamond.configure(state=DISABLED)
        connnecting box_number to button
        def box_number(self):
         self.box_number = box_number
         return box_number()



        HideTheDiamond.configure(command=connect)

        def checkGuess():
            if box_number == random:
            number_of_guesses += 1
                print("you have guessed the number")
            else:

               print("wrong.two more attemps left")
            if number_of_guesses == 3:
               print("you lost")

           checkGuess()


           window.mainloop()
```

global_number_of_guesses equals to three
global_box_number is random number or box system uses to hide the diamond in
box_number is the box user clicks on in order to find out if diamond is in there

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
global guesses
guesses = 0

def start_game():
    global location
    location = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)

def clicked(button_number):
    global guesses, location
    guesses += 1
    if guesses > 3:
        # tell the player he lost here in any way you like
        print("you lost")
    else:
        if button_number == location:
            # Tell the player he won
            print("You won")
        else:
            # The player guessed wrong but can try again...
            print("Not correct, sorry")


for i in range(1, 11):
    Button(window, command=lambda i=i: clicked(i).grid(row=i//5, column=i%5, sticky='nswe'))

b11 = Button(window, text="Click here to start the game", command=start_game)
b11.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Not the best solution but it should work.
I hope this provides some help, let me know if there are any problems with this.

Comment: `for i in range(1,11): Button(window, command=lambda: clicked(i)).pack()` What do you need names for? They aren't being used anywhere. You can turn 20 lines into 1 with identical results.

Comment: My bad, thank you for the suggestion I will change it. I first thought of a different aproach with names and didnt change it...

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be this `for i in range(1, 11): Button(window, command=lambda i=i:clicked(i)).pack()` Notice the `i` assignment in the `lambda`. Without it `i` in `clicked` will never be right. I fixed your code since I gave you incomplete info.

Comment: You have to move `guesses+=1` before the `if guesses>3` or you get 4 guesses `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: I just noticed that the OP is not using `pack`. If you want to make your solution more closely match theirs, and keep the simple button loop. Use this: 
`for i in range(0, 10):  Button(window, command=lambda i=i:clicked(i+1)).grid(row=i//5, column=i%5, sticky='nswe')`